# Creating a class in C++, that contains a class which has a constructor that takes as parameters 2 objects of type class

Tags: c++, class, object, nested

My whole purpose is to create an object "merged_lot" which takes the data from the vectors of lot a and lot b, and stores it in its own vector.

I really can't find anywhere how to actually do it. (I know I could do it more easily if I could create 2 separated classes, but I am forced to do all this in a single class).

```cpp
class lot{
   protected:
      vector<int> elements;
   public:
      //various functions of lot
      class merged_lot;
};
 class lot::merged_lot :public lot{
    public:
        merged_lot(lot a, lot b){}

};
```

Comment: It is not too clear what exactly you find difficult. Perhaps if you posted a version you can do (with 2 separate classes or whatever) it would be a bit easier to see.

Comment: well if i do it like in the code i posted
   merged_lot(lot a, lot b){
      elements=elements.a+elements.b;
   }
i get an "object a not declared" kind of error

Comment: One, if you want member `elements` of object `a`, you write `a.elements`, not `elements.a`. Two, `elements` is a vector, and `+` doesn't concatenate vectors.